# To which a,b,c values ​the function is continuous?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, derivatives

Let
$$y=\begin{cases}-3&\text{ if } & x=-1\\
\frac{x^3+ax^2+bx+c}{(x+1)^2}&\text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$
  I'm trying to find $a,b,c$ value So the function will be continuous.
Can you help me with this problem?

Comment: if $y(x)$ is continuous then it has to be a polynomial of degree $1$.

Comment: "if y(x) is continuous then it has to be a polynomial of degree 1"  What?

Comment: To be continuous $\lim\limits_{x\to -1}y_x$ must equal $y_{x=-1}$ of $\lim\limits_{x\to -1}\frac {x^3 + ax^2 +bx +c}{(x+1)^2} = -3$.  Now you should be able to figure out the $\lim\limits_{x\to -1}\frac {x^3 + ax^2 +bx +c}{(x+1)^2}=$ something to do with $a,b,c$.  So set the "something to do with $a,b,c$ = -3$ and solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be continuous $\lim\limits_{x\to -1}y_x$ must equal $y_{x=-1}$ of $\lim\limits_{x\to -1}\frac {x^3 + ax^2 +bx +c}{(x+1)^2} = -3$.  Now you should be able to figure out the $\lim\limits_{x\to -1}\frac {x^3 + ax^2 +bx +c}{(x+1)^2}=$ something to do with $a,b,c$.  So set the "something to do with $a,b,c = -3$ and solve.

In particular:

$\lim\limits_{x\to -1}\frac {x^3 + ax^2 +bx +c}{(x+1)^2}=$

$\lim\limits_{y\to 0}\frac {(y-1)^3 + a(y-1)^2 + b(y-1) + c}{y^2}=$

$\lim\limits_{y\to 0}\frac {(y^3 - 3y^2 +3y -1) + (ay^2 - 2ay + a)+(by-b) + c}{y^2}=$

$\lim\limits_{y\to 0}\frac {y^3+(a - 3)y^2 +(3-2a+b)y +a-b+c-1}{y^2}=$

$\lim\limits_{y\to 0}(y + {a-3} + \frac {3-2a +b}y + \frac{a-b+c -1}{y^2})=$

$a-3 + \lim\limits_{y\to 0} \frac{y(3-2a +b)+ a-b+c -1}{y^2}$

If $a-b+c -1 \ne 0$ then $\lim\limits_{y\to 0} \frac{y(3-2a +b)+ a-b+c -1}{y^2}$ diverges

we must have $a-b+c-1 = 0$ and:

$a-3 + \lim\limits_{y\to 0} \frac{y(3-2a +b)+ a-b+c -1}{y^2}=$

$a-3 + \lim\limits_{y\to 0} \frac{3-2a +b}{y}$

If $3-2a + b \ne 0$ then $\lim\limits_{y\to 0} \frac{3-2a +b}{y}$ diverges.

We must have $3-2a + b = 0$ and:

$a-3 + \lim\limits_{y\to 0} \frac{3-2a +b}{y}= a-3 = -3$

So we must have:

1)$a-b+c-1 = 0$

2) $3-2a + b = 0$

and 3) $a - 3 = -3$.

So $a = 0; b=-3; c=-2$.

And $\lim\limits_{x\to -1} \frac {x^3 -3x -2}{(x+1)^2}=\lim\limits_{x\to -1} \frac {x^3 -3x + 4}{x^2 + 2x + 1} = \lim\limits_{x\to -1}\frac {x^3 + 2x^2 + x -2x^2 -4x -2}{x^2 + 2x+1}=\lim\limits_{x\to -1} (x -2)= -1 -2 = -3$.

Answer (score 0):

Say $p(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$. Then $p(-1)=0$ and $p'(-1)=0$ so we have:

$$ -1+a-b+c=0$$ and

$$ 3-2a+b=0$$

Then $b=2a-3$ and $c=a-2$ so $$p(x) = (x+1)^2(x-2) +a(x+1)^2=(x+1)^2(x-2+a)$$

So $$\lim _{x\to -1} (x-2+a) = -3+a$$ so $a= 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody seems to understand my hint... :-(

Let $p(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$

By polynomial division $p(x)=(x+1)^2q(x)+r(x)$  with $\deg(q)=1$ and also $\deg(r)=1$

Thus $y(x)=q(x)+\dfrac{r(x)}{(x+1)^2}$

For $y$ to be continuous in $-1$ we need $r(x)=0$ because of the lesser degree of $r$.

Finally since the leading coefficients of $p(x)$ and $(x+1)^2$ are both $1$ then $q(x)=x-x_0$.

$y(-1)=-3\iff q(-1)=-1-x_0=-3\quad$ so $\quad x_0=2$

Finally $\begin{cases}
y(x)=q(x)=(x-2)\\
p(x)=(x-2)(x+1)^2=x^3-3x-2\end{cases}\implies a=0,\ b=-3,\ c=-2$